# Why does xxd add chars?

Tags: bash, xxd, od

I am trying to reverse an `od` command from a system where I have no `hexdump` or `base64` tools.

I do this like that (of course, in reality, the encoding takes place at the "small" system, the decoding is done on my workstation, but to test it, I try the whole way in one line first):

```
echo TEST | od -tx1 | xxd -r
```

Of course, `echo TEST` is just a placeholder here for eg. `cat test.bmp` or anything else.

```
> echo TEST
TEST

> echo TEST | od -tx1
0000000 54 45 53 54 0a
0000005 

> echo TEST | od -tx1 | xxd -r
TEST
```

That *looks* right, but it is different, as we can see here if we give it to `od` again:

```
> echo TEST | od -tx1 | xxd -r | od -tx1
0000000 54 45 53 54 0a 00 00 00
0000010
```

Why does `xxd -r` add those `00`s?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the second line of `od`'s output. Try `echo -n TEST | od -tx1 | head -1 | xxd -r | od -tx1`

Comment: No, xdd adds it: `echo TEST | od -tx1 | xxd -r | wc -c` equals to 8.

Comment: And compare `echo -n TEST | xxd | xxd -r | od -tx1`. Looking at the man page, `xxd -r` expects `xxd` style hex dumps, not an `od` one. The difference might also have something to do with it.

Comment: `echo TEST | od -tx1 | head -1 | xxd -r | wc -c` is 5. It's something about that second line that od prints not matching the input format that `xxd -r` expects. The old saying is 'Garbage In, Garbage Out'.

Comment: also the address are in octal with od (except `-Ax`) whereas hexa in xxd. compare `printf 'hello\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0world' | od -Ax -tx1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work if I remove the offsets at all:

```
> echo TEST | od -tx1 -An
 54 45 53 54 0a
> echo TEST | od -tx1 -An | xxd -r -p
TEST
> echo TEST | od -tx1 -An | xxd -r -p | od -tx1 -An
 54 45 53 54 0a
```

Bingo! Note the extra " " in front of the bytes. It seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting those three nul bytes because of `xxd -r` trying and failing to parse input that's in a different format than what it expects. `od -tx1` adds an extra line with an offset but no data bytes. Plus the offsets in `xxd` have a colon after them, and are printed with a different width, and printable bytes are displayed as well as the hex dump, and possibly in a different base... Something about that doesn't play well with `xxd`, and it adds the extra bytes as a result.

Examples:

```
$ echo TEST | xxd
00000000: 5445 5354 0a                             TEST.
$ echo TEST | xxd | xxd -r
TEST
$ echo TEST | xxd | xxd -r | xxd    
00000000: 5445 5354 0a                             TEST.
$ echo TEST | xxd | xxd -r | od -tx1
0000000 54 45 53 54 0a
0000005
$ echo TEST | od -tx1 | head -1 | xxd -r | od -tx1 
0000000 54 45 53 54 0a
0000005
```

See how they're not present when giving `xxd -r` its expected `xxd` style input? And how they're not there when you prune that extra line from `od`'s output? Don't mix and match incompatible data formats.